# Host Blazor Server on Apache Windows

Tags: c#, windows, apache, blazor-server-side, virtualhost

I am trying to host a Blazor Server app on a Windows where we are running Apache. We are running several sites on this server so we are using the vhost section to configure different sites. I read on this link that you can via ProxyPass host a Blazor Server app on Apache for Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#linux-with-apache

If I run the Blazor Server app in Kestrel on port 5000 (or any other port). How can I on Windows create a VirtualHost in Apache that hosts the Blazor Server app in similar way as in above mentioned article?